# Semisimplicity of étale cohomology representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, reference-request

Let $K$ be a number field and $G=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ the absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $\ell$ be a prime number.

Let $A/K$ be an abelian variety. Then the representation of $G$ on $V_\ell(A)$ is semisimple. This is the famous theorem of Faltings (Invent. Math. 73).

Now let $X/K$ be a smooth projective variety and $0\le q\le 2\dim(X)$, and define $\overline{X}=X_{\overline{K}}$.

**Question.** Is it known that the representation of $G$ on $H^q(\overline{X}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell)$is semisimple?

**Remark.** The answer is yes for $q=1$, because $H^1(\overline{X}, Q_\ell)$ is dual to
$V_\ell(A)$ where $A$ is the Albanese variety of $X$.

I would also be interested in the case where the number field $K$ is replaced by a global function field (say), and $\ell$ is assumed to be coprime to the characteristic.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the answer is "no" in the number field case, and it is surely "no" over finite fields (already).

Comment: Thx for your comment! I somehow expected a "not known" in the number field case as well. Why is the answer a definite "no" over finite fields? I do not know how to prove this. Can you give me a view details on that?

Comment: Sorry, just to be sure: Do you mean "not known" or "false" in the case of a finite ground field?

Comment: One more comment: My question is exactly conjecture $SS^i(X)$ in Tate's article "Conjectures on algebraic cycles on l-adic cohomology", Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics 55 (the motives volume I). So my question is, whether there has been progress on this conjecture since this article was written. 

Comment: Joel Bellaiche's Hawaii notes http://people.brandeis.edu/~jbellaic/BKHawaii4.pdf (page 5) say: "This is sometimes called “conjecture of Grothendieck-Serre”. This is known for abelian varieties, by a theorem that Faltings proved at the same times he proved the Mordell’s conjecture, and in a few other cases (some Shimura varieties, for example)." (But that's all he says.)

Comment: It seems that the status of your questions did not change significantly in the last few decades; cf. Emerton's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This semi-simplicity is a part of what is called the Tate conjecture.  It is generally believed to be true, but little is known about it outside the case of $H^1$, in either the finite field or global field case.  Searching on mathscinet for "Tate conjecture" (or googling) should turn up the relevant literature.

Comment: This conjecture is discussed in the recent interview 
with John Tate 
(http://www.ams.org/notices/201103/rtx110300444p.pdf) 
in the *Notices* of the AMS.

Answer (score 5):

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04489.pdf, Moonen proves that for finitely generated fields of characteristic $0$, the Tate conjecture (surjectivity of the cycle class map $\mathrm{CH}^r(X) \otimes \mathbf{Q}_\ell \to \mathrm{H}^{2r}(\bar{X},\mathbf{Q}_\ell)^{G_K}$) implies the semisimplicity conjecture.

(For the Tate conjecture, see e.g. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~chaoli/docs/TateConjecture.html or Tate's article in the *Motives* volume.)